# RD Session Host Configuration referencing server on old domain, unable to provide administrative credentials

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

A Server 2008R2 machine (server01) has been moved from and old domain (old.domain) to a new domain (new.domain). It runs its own standalone RD Session Host, and it still referencing the old domain (server01.old.domain) within Licensing Diagnosis.

It advises that "To identity possible licensing issues, administrator credentials for license server server01.old.domain are required". However none of the old domain admin logins will authenticate, and none of the new domain logins will work (I'm logged in via the console as a domain admin on the new domain, and am a member of the local Administrators group).

I've activated the local Administrator account and tried opening Licensing Diagnosis with this, however it advises me that I must be using a domain based account.

I need to remove the reference to server-01.old.domain and change this to server-01.new.domain, but I simply can't work out how. I'm wondering if there's an area in the registry that I can modify to resolve this.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Auto discovery of license servers is disabled from 2K8R2 onwards. One must have to explicitly configure the license server in each RDSH either through GP or Registry or through scripts.

```
$obj = gwmi -namespace "Root/CIMV2/TerminalServices" Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
$obj.SetSpecifiedLicenseServerList("server-01.new.domain")
```

Please see below links on how to configure License servers on 2K8R2 RDSH machines.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh553158(v=ws.10).aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770585.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please see the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TermService\Parameters\LicenseServers` regkey and the following document: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737644(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope this helps.

/cd